# How to properly deploy a Django app while following 12FA?

Tags: python, django, deployment, cicd, 12factor

I am deploying a Django app and I got stuck. I am trying to follow the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) principles. Specifically, they state that you should have all your configuration in environment variables. Also, I don't want to have multiple `settings.py` files, because that goes against the 12FA principles. So, I have simply a single `settings.py` file, which checks environment variables using `os.environ['xxx']` for stuff like database login etc.

On the local dev machine, these environment variables are pulled from a file called `.env`. On the server, I am planning to store all the environment variables inside a systemd unit using the `Environment=` syntax.

Now, my problem occurs while deploying. I copy all the source Python files onto the server, and I need to call `collectstatic` and `migrate`. However, these actions both require the presence of a `settings.py` file which needs to have access to the database. However, `collectstatic` is called from my CI/CD pipeline and doesn't have all those environment variables; the **only** place where they're stored is the systemd unit file which has very limited permissions (only root can read and write to the file).

My question is, what approach could I take in order to follow 12FA while maintaining a single `settings.py` file?

Comment: Any reason you can't run `collectstatic` and `migrate` in your deployment environment instead of (or in addition to) your CICD pipeline? Applying the benefits of the 12FA, you could also use different configuration in your CICD pipeline and that should be OK. I'm not sure I see the obstacle in using a single settings.py file.

Comment: @sytech well I can run it in the deployment environment. But the settings.py file uses environment variables that are written only in a single place: the systemd unit. Thus, the systemd unit will have to run `collectstatic`. I don't know if it's a good idea to run both `collectstatic` and `migrate` at each restart of the Django server.